# Taking values with at least one specified values from another column

Tags: python, regex, if-statement, lambda, pandas-apply

I have this dataset

```
custID     documentno    quantity    producttype
1          1281261658       3        accesories
1          1281261658       3        major
1          1281261658       3        accesories
2          0105162445       2        major      
2          0105162445       2        major
3          0100848728       2        major
3          0100848728       2        accesories
4          0106075074       1        major
```

So, I want to filter the dataset in a way I want documentno's with atleast one 'accesories' in it. So I want to remove documents with only 'major' in it.

```
custID = {1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4}
documentno = {1281261658,1281261658,1281261658,0105162445,0105162445,0100848728,0100848728,0106075074}
quantity = {3,3,3,2,2,2,2,1}
producttype = {'accesories','major','accesories','major','major','major','accesories','major'}
```

the final result is:

```
id     documentno   quantity    producttype
1      1281261658      3        accesories
1      1281261658      3        major
1      1281261658      3        accesories
3      0100848728      2        major
3      0100848728      2        accesories
```

I tried with if else, but I couldn't do it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `pd.DataFrame` `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4],
                   'documentno' : ['1281261658','1281261658','1281261658','0105162445','0105162445','0100848728','0100848728','0106075074'],
                   'quantity' : [3,3,3,2,2,2,2,1],
                   'producttype' : ['accesories','major','accesories','major','major','major','accesories','major']})
```

Try the following:

`df.loc[df.documentno.isin(df.documentno[df.producttype.eq('accesories')].unique()),:]`

Result is:

```
   id  documentno  quantity producttype
0   1  1281261658         3  accesories
1   1  1281261658         3       major
2   1  1281261658         3  accesories
5   3  0100848728         2       major
6   3  0100848728         2  accesories
```

As a filter `df.documentno[df.producttype.eq('accesories')]` is used which returns `documentno` values that have one or more `accesories`.
I assume that `quantity` in dataset `df` is always greatest than 0.

However if `quantity` may be zero:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4],
                   'documentno' : ['1281261658','1281261658','1281261658','0105162445','0105162445','0100848728','0100848728','0106075074'],
                   'quantity' : [3,3,3,2,2,2,0,1],
                   'producttype' : ['accesories','major','accesories','major','major','major','accesories','major']})
```

just add condition `df.quantity.gt(0)`:

```
df.loc[ df.documentno.isin(df.documentno[(df.producttype.eq('accesories') & df.quantity.gt(0))].unique()) ,:]
```

Comment: Of course I made the same typo :-) Already edited answer. Is it ok now?

Comment: Even after the typo, I still get the same thing. It still shows documents with only major.

Comment: Is the data You are working on exactly the same as in example provided? If no an extra data cleaning steps may be required.

Comment: Its the same, the example is just a sample of it.

Comment: The typo is I made while posting here, there are no typos in the original data.

Comment: I've added reproductible example to my answer. See comments. Result is as expected IMHO. If something is wrong please provide data to reproduce errors.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I have done it in another method. ;). You can find my method in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method I followed,

First making another column with number of different product types in for a document

```
df['n_cats'] = df.groupby('documentno')['producttype'].transform('nunique')
```

Then dropping the values which are only with major

```
df = df.drop(df[(df['n_cats'] == 1) & (df['producttype'] == 'major')].index)
```

Thank you

Comment: Please notice that finding <documentno's with at least one 'accesories' in it> is not the same as <removing documentsno's with only 'major'>. If dataset may contain more values than ('accesories','major') - the above solution will not work.